# How can I find the columns of a disabled index constraint?

Tags: oracle, constraints, data-dictionary

For a normal index constraint, you can find the columns it is on by querying the `all_ind_columns` sysview using the index name in `all_constraints`. But if the constraint is disabled, no index exists, and there doesn't seem to be anywhere else that has constraint column information. How can I get the columns of a disabled index constraint from the data dictionary (without re-enabling the constraint)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about ALL_CONS_COLUMMS? Seems to work find for disabled constraints of types U and P.